# How do you connect a tab bar item to an action?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, interface-builder, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a UIView which has a UITabBar with 4 UITabBarItem components in it (all created from IB).

I want my IBAction function called when someone clicks on the items in the tab bar.  But I am unable to connect the tabbaritem to my action via IB... I control drag from the "received actions" but it does not allow me to connect that to the tabbaritem.

Thanks
Deshawn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear from your question if you also defined a UITabBarController.

If you did not (as I assume, otherwise clicking on a tab bar item should work if you correctly defined things in IB), the way to go is assigning a UITabBarDelegate to your UITabBar and define `tabBar:didSelectItem:`

Have a look at the [reference for UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar:didSelectItem:)

Comment: Hi... My interface looks like this : @interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>

Answer (score 14):

Control drag your tabbar to your "File's owner" in IB and set it as the delegate.  Next drop this code in your viewcontroller.m file:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.tag == 0)
    {
        //party like its 1999 right here
    }
}
```

Go back to IB and set each tab bar item in your tab bar with a tag.  You gotta test for each case in your didSelectItem, so if you got more than one set a different tag etc.  Thats how I did it anyway.

Comment: This sounded like the most promising lead for me, but where the heck is this "File's owner" are you talk about? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a target action to your tab bar items. They should always have a new view. The only way is - you should use delegates which determine that your tabbar item is touched and then handle which tab is pressed in that delegate.

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.tag == 1)
    {
    }
}
```

You should set a tag value to your tab bar item from the properties in xcode.

Comment: Hi! What if one wants a "Touch down" action recognized on a TabBar Item (Instead of "selected" action)? How would that be done?