# how do I make an event when a tab button is pressed?

Tags: ios, events, tabbar

I need to fire an event when a tab button has been pressed from the tab bar in Xcode. I am clueless to do this? can someone help me?

Comment: have you checked apple docs, or tried anything yet?

Comment: I tried this one..its not calling - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(DetailViewController *)viewController{
    NSLog(@"T APPEA");
}

Comment: put some code.. edit your answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UITabBarDelegate to your UITabBar and define tabBar:didSelectItem:

as described here :
[How do you connect a tab bar item to an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891908/how-do-you-connect-a-tab-bar-item-to-an-action)