# How do I connect a tab view item to an action ? (Cocoa on OS X)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to link a tab of a OS X Cocoa Tab View to a specific action, but ctrl+drag doesn't work.
I [found an other post of somebody that had about the same problem than I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891908/how-do-you-connect-a-tab-bar-item-to-an-action), but it was on iOS and I am failing to adapt this to OS X. I don't understand if I am failing because I am not using the good functions or if it is for another reason.

Here is what I am doing when trying to adapt the method given on the other post :
[image]

First, I ctrl+drag from the Tab View to "File's Owner" and make it the delegate of this.

Then, I add this code to AppDelegate.h :

```
- (void)tabBar:(NSTabView *)tabBar didSelectItem:(NSTabViewItem *)item
```

And on AppDelegate.m :

```
- (void)tabBar:(NSTabView *)tabBar didSelectItem:(NSTabViewItem *)item
{
    if([item.identifier isEqualTo:@1])
    {
        NSLog(@"Click !");
    }
}
```

*The identifier of my tab "Apprendre" is 1.*

**The problem is that when I run this code, nothing appears in the console when I click on the "Apprendre" tab. Do you know where I am wrong ?**

Comment: So what have you set the tab view item identifier to?  It's certainly not `@(1)`, which is an `NSNumber`.

Comment: @trojanfoe The tab view item identifier is "1". Is it a NSString ?!

Comment: Then the comparison would be `@"1"` not `@1`, given identifiers are strings.

Comment: @trojanfoe I does not work even when I put @"1" :(

Comment: Then you have not set the identifier correctly.  Your approach is correct, however.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am not completely sure whether it is my identifier that is the problem because even if I put a NSLog out of the condition, I don't get anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52368/discussion-between-trevor-anne-denise-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong method.

```
- (void)tabBar:(NSTabView *)tabBar didSelectItem:(NSTabViewItem *)item
```

Instead it should be

```
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem
```

This is very straight forward.

Hook the `NSTabView` to the `AppDelegate` for delegate. (Be sure that you hook correctly to the TabView itself not its parts)

[image]

Then check for the Identifier and Label for each of the tabs:
[image]

Then the delegate method goes like this:

```
- (void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem{

    if ([tabViewItem.identifier isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        NSLog(@"ONE");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"TWO");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `File's Owner` is `NSApplication` so the delegate should probably be `App Delegate` instead.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I didn't get you. The above is working fine.

Comment: The OP's `File's Owner` is `NSApplication` not `AppDelegate`, so I'm not sure connecting to `File's Owner` is correct (for them at least).

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Finally I solved my issue, I was simply not using the good method !

Comment: @trojanfoe I solved my problem, in fact I was not using the good method ! And it looks like you are right for the File's owner, because it works only if I connect it to App Delegate.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: Oh yaa, you have used **`TabBar`** not `TabView`.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks for your answer ! I suggest you to edit your post, because it works only when linking to App Delegate ! It doesn't work when I link it to File's owner.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: Yeah I noticed it. You hooked to file's owner. not to appDelegate. Also thanks to `trojanfoe`.