# How to view a new ViewContrloller (do an action) if tab bar item pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbar

well, I'm trying to connect 3 view controllers with 3 tab bar items in one tab bar, I searched here for the way and I found multiple answers such as: [How do you connect a tab bar item to an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891908/how-do-you-connect-a-tab-bar-item-to-an-action][1])
and [set up an action with a tab bar item - iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575430/set-up-an-action-with-a-tab-bar-item-iphone][1]) but i could not figure it out, here is my code:

```
class TabBar: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

        if(item.tag == 1) {
            let us = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Th5ViewController") as! Th5ViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController( us, animated: true)

        }
        else if(item.tag == 2) {
            //your code for tab item 2
        }

        else if(item.tag == 3) {
            //your code for tab item 2
        }

    }
}
```

so, what I missed? I think it a small rational detail. thank you.

Comment: 1. Why do you call a UIViewController subclass `TabBar`? TabBar is a suitable name for a view, not a controller. 2. What `navigationController` are you referring to? Do you really need to push a new view controller if a tab bar item is selected or just to show a view controller for that tab?

Comment: @alexburtnik I used the same way I knew it when I set an action to a button with new view controller, and yes I want to push new view controller if the first tab bar item is selected, the others just to show their view controllers.

Comment: If you already connect 3 view controller to 3 tabbar item, you can simply do action when that viewcontroller appear in their `viewWillAppear`, since when press the tabbar item, it will bring you to that view controller anyway? Or you need to do any specific action?